# Python/DJango Attribute error : Model object has not attribute objects

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-queryset

forms.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from pset.models import problem , testcases 

class problems(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=problem
        fields=['pcode','pdesc']

class testcases(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=testcases
        fields=['pcode','inp','out']

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(testcases,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['pcode']=forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_list())


def get_list() :
    tup=((x,x) for x in problem.object.values_list('pcode',flat=True))
    return tup
```

here are two modelforms one is problems and other one is testcases .
I was trying to include a dropdown menu in it. 
For it tried to include the pcode column from problem Model.

But don't know why it is shooting up an error :

**AttributeError at /setup/add_cases/
type object 'problem' has no attribute 'object'**
in the function get_list .

In case required :

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here. 
class problem(models.Model) :
    pcode=models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
    pdesc=models.TextField() 

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.pcode   

class testcases(models.Model):
    pcode=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    inp=models.FileField(upload_to='testcases',blank=True)
    out=models.FileField(upload_to='testcases',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pcode
```

apologies if any detail has been left out .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo on this line:

```
problem.object.values_list('pcode',flat=True))
```

You are missing the 's' from objects.

```
problem.objects.values_list('pcode',flat=True))
```

As an aside, the convention is to use CamelCase for your Django models, and have them singular not plural, e.g. `Problem` and `TestCase` instead of `problem` and `testcases`.

Comment: aah !! i had myself replaced objects by object when error was there earlier and when and after removing it that replacement was showing error !! anyways thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

You just mistype, in your `get_list` function it should be `objects` not `object`.

```
def get_list() :
    tup=((x,x) for x in problem.objects.values_list('pcode',flat=True))
    return tup
```